# Add title attribute based on checked/unchecked

Tags: angular

I wanted to add `title` attribute to radio buttons based on checked/unchecked.

I'm unable to do it in Angular 2.

Below is is my code. Please help

```html
<input id="radio{{i}}" name="radio" type="radio">

< span class="radioLabel">
  < label class="custom-control-description" for="radio{{i}}" [checked]=" 'tooltip=" checked " : 'tooltip="unchecked "' tooltipPlacement="bottom "> 
    < /label>
      < / span>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use on click event on radio button. Click event will give you mouse event of clicked radio button. Your code will look like this:

```
<input id="radio{{i}}" name="radio" type="radio" (click)="addTitleAttribute($event)">
```

Now add functionality in your component. Use following code in component:

```
addTitleAttribute(event: MouseEvent) {
 let radio = event.target as HTMLInputElement;
 radio.setAttribute("title", "valueOfTitle");
 // other logic will go here
}
```

Hope it will help